# How to get duplicates in a column and copy into another sheet with some other particular column

Tags: excel, vba

For Ex:

[image]

I want to get the duplicates in B column along with its values in D column and paste that only in another sheet.

I'm using the below code:

```
              Sub FindPIDDuplicates()
              
              Dim wstSource As Worksheet, _
                  wstOutput As Worksheet
              Dim rngMyData As Range, _
                  helperRng As Range
              
              Set wstSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
              'ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet2"
              Set wstOutput = Worksheets("Sheet2")
              
              Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
              Set trg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
               src.Range("1:1").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("A1")
              
              Application.ScreenUpdating = False
              
              With wstSource
                  Set rngMyData = .Range("A1:H" & .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
              End With
              Set helperRng = rngMyData.Offset(, rngMyData.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 1)
              
              With helperRng
                  .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(countif(C1,RC1)>1,"""",1)"
                  .Value = .Value
                  .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=wstOutput.Cells(2, 1)
                  .ClearContents
              End With
              
              Application.ScreenUpdating = True
              
              End Sub
```

Kindly guide me to achieve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? Which part of the code is causing what problem?

Comment: `countif(C1,RC1)` doesn't look right, have you looked up RC syntax?

Comment: it is always getting duplicates from A column only, and copying all other columns to the another sheet.

Comment: Tip: put the formulas on the sheet manually until everything looks like you want. Select the first formula, Go to immediate-window in VBA-Editor, type `?selection.formular1c1` + Enter --> then you get the formula you need for your VBA code.